# Is it possible to send Data to a PHP Skript like this (AJAX)?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, get

```
methods: {
        ajax: function (task, callback, variables) {
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            let send = "&variables=" + encodeURIComponent(variables);
            // console.log(variables[0], variables[1], variables[2], variables[3], variables[4]);
            xhr.open("GET", "db_data.php?task=" + encodeURIComponent(task) + send, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
                    let json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    callback(json); // Um Tabelle anzuzeigen
                    console.log(json);
                }
            }
            xhr.send(null);
        }

submit: function () {
            document.querySelector(app.selectors.ids.absenden).addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                let vals = [
                    document.querySelector(app.selectors.ids.projektnummer).value,
                    document.querySelector(app.selectors.ids.beschreibung).value,
                    document.querySelector(app.selectors.ids.startdatum).value,
                    document.querySelector(app.selectors.ids.enddatum).value,
                    document.querySelector(app.selectors.ids.budget).value
                ];
                app.methods.ajax(app.task.create_project, () => {}, vals)

            });
        }
    }
```

The code is an excerpt from a program, which in this case sends data that is typed into a form to a PHP script and then changes a database entry. My question is whether you can pass vals in the submit function to the Ajax function in the form and whether the Ajax function can then send the data to the PHP script.
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: you would probably want to JSON encode the variables using `JSON.stringify` but also consider using the `fetch` api instead of XMLHttpRequest ~ it is far more powerful and flexible

Comment: Named variables would also make more sense than a simple array of values - there would be no means on the server to know what is what

Comment: The question is how can I access the data in the PHP script @ADyson

Comment: Well why didn't you ask that question then? Variables sent in the querystring of a URL, as shown above, are always accessed via $_GET in PHP. If you send a POST request and put data in the request body, then you can access it via $_POST - again this is standard info that you can already read about in any related tutorial, or in the PHP manual.

Comment: The only slight issue you've got here is that you've encoded the entire `variables` array into a single comma-separated string within one URL parameter. While that's do-able, and your PHP could retrieve them into a usable array with `$variables = explode(",", $_GET["variables"]`, it's somewhat less than optimal - especially if anyone sends a comma inside one of the fields.

Comment: P.S. Just for future reference: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question). See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

A small example of how to send a form to PHP

I was able to do it with the post method to not encode the text strings.

First create the script function

```html
   <script>
   function sendText(){
   var txt = document.getElementById("txt").value;
   var dataForm = new FormData();
   dataForm.append('task',txt);
   jQuery.ajax({
   url: "/db_data.php?",
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   data: dataForm,
   type: "POST", success:function(data){ }
   }); return true;
   }
   </script>
```

And the php part to process the received text by inserting it into the database

```php
    <?php
     $host = "localhost:3306";
     $dbuser = "root";
     $dbpwd = "password";
     $db = "my_db";
   
   $txt = $_POST['task'];
   $conf = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $db);
   mysqli_query($conf,"INSERT INTO my_table (text) VALUES ('$txt')") or die("".mysqli_connect_error()."");
    ?>
```

in html

```html
   <form action="" method="post">
   <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
   <input type="button"  onclick="return sendText();" value="Send"/>
   </form>
```